# why is my html-css backgrpung image reapeating?

Tags: html, css

The background image:

[image]

what the page shows:

[My website](https://tamescalytest.chadfreeman.repl.co/)

I generated the image file using the colorzilla CSS gradient generator, then converted the base64 to an SVG because I thought that would fix it but guess what.. it didn't.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<div>
  <style>
    div {
      /* Location of the image */
      background: url(https://tamescalytest.chadfreeman.repl.co/static/image.svg) center center cover no-repeat fixed;
      background-color: #464646;
    }
  </style>

  <head>
    <title>Flask Template</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="/user">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"></input>
      <input type="submit" value="go to your page"></input>
    </form>
  </body>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: You have some serious problems with your markup. l encourage you to find an HTML validator, stat. Divs don't belong outside the body, style elements don't belong outside the head, and input tags are self-closing, for starters. Also, don't apply a background image to every one of the most common elements in a website. Use a class to be more specific.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks I've been learning HTML.. but those input tags weren't me that was a template I'm not that much of a beginner

Comment: You need to fix your markup so it's valid or the question will be closed. It's essentially unanswerable as it is.

Comment: `background-size: 100%` use that instead of `cover` And remove `background-color`

Comment: The website you linked does not have the background CSS you posted i the post !!! ???

Comment: Oh my hesus this code really is bad, and this was only last year ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

To make the background image not repeat, use `background-repeat: no-repeat`. The repeat is caused because the size of the image does not match the size of the HTML element. To make the image size cover the element try `background-size: cover`. You could also try `background-size: contain` as well.

To achieve this gradient, you could use the following code:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #01ffe9, #f25c86);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The real reason behind this is that you are using invalid CSS. A quote from the [CSS `background` docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp#midcontentadcontainer):

> If one of the properties in the shorthand declaration is the bg-size property,
> you must use a / (slash) to separate it from the bg-position property, e.g.
> background:url(smiley.gif) 10px 20px/50px 50px; will result in a background
> image, positioned 10 pixels from the left, 20 pixels from the top, and the
> size of the image will be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels high.

`bg-size` is `cover` in your case, and `bg-position` is `center center`. You do not have a slash in between `cover` and `center center`, where you ***must*** have one.

Additionally, you should give the background div a class or better an id and usse that in the CSS selector, because else, all your divs will have that gradient as background, which probably isn't what you want.

Following the tidied and working code with using classes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div#formbackground {
      /* Location of the image */
      background: url(https://tamescalytest.chadfreeman.repl.co/static/image.svg) center center/cover no-repeat fixed;
      background-color: #464646;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Flask Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="formbackground">
    <form action="/user">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
      </br>
      <input type="submit" value="go to your page"></input>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```